# Return a String from method instead of printing to System.out

Tags: java, json

I wrote the below code that prints multiple E shapes made of asterisks. I would like to know how I can return a `String` from the method rather than printing to `System.out`. When I try it using String append, it just returns a single line of asterisks rather than the E shapes that I want.

Return can be a string method or a JSON format. Any help would be great!

```
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    String print = i % 2 == 0 ? "*****    " : "*        ";
    for(int j=0; j < numberOfE; j++) {
        System.out.print(print);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I don't follow the question.  Can you include the code for the entire method?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `System.out.print()` with a string append, but also remember to replace `System.out.println()` with appending a newline character to your string.

```
String ans = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String print = i % 2 == 0 ? "*****    " : "*        ";
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfE; j++) {
        ans += print;
    }
    ans += '\n';
}
return ans;
```

It's also more efficient to use a `StringBuilder` rather than appending to a `String`, although the difference is probably not noticeable for your scenario:

```
StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String print = i % 2 == 0 ? "*****    " : "*        ";
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfE; j++) {
        ans.append(print);
    }
    ans.append('\n');
}
return ans.toString();
```

Comment: Better to use a StringBuilder I think

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sure, but learning to program happens one step at a time. :)

Comment: I think its good to mention `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` for the future, but like you said @pkpnd , no need to get wrapped up in it for now. Good answer :)

Comment: I built a small test and StringBuilder was significantly faster - by about an order of magnitude for each time I increased the loop by an order of magnitude.  E.g. if I did 10x more iterations then StringBuilder was ~10x faster.  But you had to get up above 1000 iterations of the loop for the difference to be significant.  (At 100k the difference is actually quite severe)

Comment: @Rick That performance is entirely what I would have expected, but I doubt OP is running more than a handful of loop iterations.